# Unable to specify Model->alias

Tags: cakephp

I'm using a custom Class in my program which can connect to multiple tables as and when I need to.

I'm trying to create a new instance of the class, and I can pass in a different table name and alias via the constructor. This works for the table name, but it doesn't set the Model alias as it should in the documentation

Creating an new Object. The Class being instantiated is Lists

```
$lists = new Lists(null, 'list_musicians', null, null, 'Musician');
```

Class Constructor

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null, $name = null, $alias) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds, $name, $alias);
    $this->virtualFields['full_name'] = sprintf(
        'CONCAT(%s.first_name, " ", %s.last_name)', $this->alias, $this->alias
    );

    //debug($this->alias);die;
}
```

This will connect to the table named 'list_musicians' or whatever table name I pass in, but the `$alias` field does not get assigned to `$this->alias`
If I reassign the alias manually, the virtual fields are not included in the same array as the result, as specified in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases). The alias is always `Lists`

How can I set the model alias via the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using a custom Class in my program which can connect to multiple
>   tables as and when I need to.

Honestly that's a pretty bad idea in the most cases. If you already read the MVC chapter from of the book read it again, if not read it now.

And you're wrong, the constructor of the model class **doesn't** know a 4th argument for the alias, [check your own link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases) and read it again.

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null)
```

However, if you want to insist on bad practice you can always instantiate Model objects by using [ClassRegistry::init()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-ClassRegistry.html#_init).

> Examples Simple Use: Get a Post model instance
>   ClassRegistry::init('Post');
>
> Expanded: array('class' => 'ClassName', 'alias' =>
>   'AliasNameStoredInTheRegistry');
>
> Model Classes can accept optional array('id' => $id, 'table' =>
>   $table, 'ds' => $ds, 'alias' => $alias);

Just use `Model` as class name and provide whatever table you want.

Comment: There are about 6 to 8 db tables that house varying lists of information, that for the most part its a case of id and name thats needed, or ID and virtual field. I don't see the reason in having separate models and views for each one, since its common functionality and I'm trying to keep the project DRY. I'm hoping to call the model from whatever controller I need to generate a list for the associated view. If what I'm looking to do is not good MVC practice what's the solution, as I think that all separate basically empty models is unnecessary bloating.

Comment: I cant answer that without knowing the schema. If all tables are the same then I would ask why you're not adding a type field instead and make it one table. ClassRegistry::init() should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this is just to create model associations directly to the db tables. Use the table name as the classname and voila

```
'Religion' => array(
        'className' => 'list_religions',
        'foreignKey' => 'religion_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
```